# Play MP4 video using JMF

Tags: java, mp4, video-player, jmf

How to play MP4 video using JMF?

I am creating Java application. I want to play MP4 file using JMF. I tried to play MP4 file but it throws exception

```
Could not create player for filename.mp4
```

Mpg format working fine for me. But I have only MP4 files.

Code:

```
Player mediaPlayer = Manager.createRealizedPlayer( mediaURL );
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085522/playing-media-files-using-java

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [JMF 2.1.1 - Supported Formats](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/formats-138492.html) page and do a find on 'mp4'.  You'll notice no hits.

There is an old saying *"You can't make a silk purse from a pig's ear"*.  In this case *"play MP4"* is the *"silk purse"* and *"JMF"* is the *"pig's ear"*.  JMF is far too old to support a wide variety of formats (many of which were released after the development on JMF ceased).

Answer (score 1):

JMF is obsolete and buggy.

JavaCV is a modern library for processing video based on OpenCV / FFMPEG and also supports 64bit which JMF does not.