# How to play mp4 video in JAVA (swing) jframe using vlcj?Is there any other way to play mp4 in JAVA?

Tags: java, video, netbeans-7, vlcj, video-player

I want to play video file in JAVA(java swing).

I have used JMF(java media framework). But it support .mpg format only.

I want to play .mp4 format video file.

How to do this?

I could play mpg video using this code

```
 mediaPlayer1.setMediaLocation("file:///C:/mpgvdo/Best_Song2.mpg");
 mediaPlayer1.start();
```

I want to know how i could use vlcj to play mp4 files.I need complete steps.starting from vlcj
installation.

I have included vlcj jar file in netbeans library also added to palette but I did not find vlc player.

Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to play a mp4 file , then it is so easy

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("test.mp4"));
```

But If you want to play it specifically in JFrame
Then keep in mind that JMF is not supporting `mp4`.[Here you can see the support formats](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/formats-138492.html).So for this I suggest you to use [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler) which is an awesome API AFAIK.A very [good example with code is present here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/introduction-xuggler-video-manipulation.html)
As far as vlcj concerns, [here you can find](http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/wiki/QuickStart) a very good quick start guide and some [simple code examples are present here](http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/wiki/SimpleExamples)

Comment: i have got some idea from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085522/playing-media-files-using-java

Comment: but I could not find a mediaplayer in swing palette.so I could not use

   player.startMedia("file:///"+myfilepath1);

   player.pause(); 

   player.play();

Comment: "Warning"
the class must be compiled and must be on class path of the project to which the form belongs

Comment: error
"The component cannot be instantiated.Please make sure it is JavaBeans component"