# Display a stream video in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, stream, jframe

I'm trying to display a stream video in a JFrame. The stream will come from an internet URL, or to be simple at first from my computer.

I would like to retrieve this stream and then display it in a JFrame. Do you guys know some librairies to do it? I already searched a lot but I can't find anything very relevant. I don't even know which component I have to use.

Please, feel free to ask me some clarifications if you don't understand what I would like to achieved.

Thank you!

EDIT : SOLVED, I had to use the 64 bits VLC version, and not the 32 bits.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to play mp4 video in JAVA (swing) jframe using vlcj?Is there any other way to play mp4 in JAVA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540794/how-to-play-mp4-video-in-java-swing-jframe-using-vlcjis-there-any-other-way-t)

Comment: Try vlcj http://www.capricasoftware.co.uk/projects/vlcj/index.html.

Comment: Not a duplicate, I do not want to use JMF. Deprecated (@MyNameIsRui)

Comment: @esprittn : Thank you ! Do you know if I have to have a 32bits version of VLC to run it ?

Comment: I not sure but this depend on what is you JVM version 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: I'm on 64bits JVM. But I can't find the required files vlc.dll and vlccore.dll (http://www.capricasoftware.co.uk/projects/vlcj/tutorial1.html)